# $(x_n) \in c_0$, $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}=\sum \frac{1}{n^2}x_n$, and $\sup|x_n|=1$ implies $|x_n|=1,\:\: \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(x_n) \in c_0$

$\sum \frac{1}{n^2}=\sum \frac{1}{n^2}x_n$ and $\sup|x_n|=1$ .

As a final step in some exercise my book claims that from these two conditions, $|x_n|=1 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How come so?

$c_0=\{\text{Space of all sequences whose limit goes to zero}\}$

EDIT: **Complete question:**
**Is it true that for all $f \in X^*$ such that $\|f\|=1$ there exists $x \in X$ so that $\|x\|=1$ and $f(x)=1$. Hint: Take $X=c_0$ and $(a_i) \in l^1$
so that $a_i \neq 0 \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$**

**Solution**
Consider $f=(a_n)_n \in l^1$ defined by $a_n= \frac{1}{n^2}(\sum \frac{1}{n^2})^{-1}$ So $f: c_0 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $f((x_n)_n)= a_n= (\sum \frac{1}{n^2})^{-1} \sum \frac{1}{n^2}x_n$.

Since we want $\sup|x_n|=1$ and $f((x_n)_n)=1$, we need to satisfy $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}=\sum \frac{1}{n^2}x_n$ which together with $\sup|x_n|=1$ yields $|x_n|=1$, so $x$ is not in $c_0$

Comment: what does $(x_n) \in c_0$ mean?

Comment: @Silva I added the definition, in case is a non standard thing

Comment: But $x_1=\sum_n 1/n^2>1$.

Comment: I assume what is meant is that $ \frac{\pi^2}{6} =\sum \frac{1}{n^2}x_n\ $ ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I think so

Comment: I added the complete question , just in case it makes more sense. Alternatives counterexamples are welcome!

Comment: Clearly there's something wrong in the statement of the problem: if $(x_n) \in c_0$ then it's impossible to have $|x_n| = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @jjagmath If you read after the edit, it becomes apparent that the entire question was asked inside a _reductio ad absurdum_ proof context.  Ignoring the problems of asking such a question without including the context... it's better to view this question as assuming that $x \in \ell^\infty$ with the given properties and then showing necessarily that $x \not\in c_0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring How do I address the fact that  the proof given below, only considers that one $x_n$ has module less than 1, which leads quite obviusly to the contradiction, but there could be a ton of combinations on non zero $x_n$ that keep the sum the same if more than one is supposed to have module less than 1?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO What you're describing cannot happen.  If all the $x_n=1$, we have a maximum to the series.  If any $x_n < 1$, the sum will be less.

Comment: @BrianMoehring but we could have some negative contributions that cancel the positive ones

Comment: That could only make the absolute value of the sum smaller.  Also note that the proof given by Jens below already includes this.  We never assume only one $x_n < 1$, just that if $x$ is not the constant sequence of all $1$s, there will be at least one index $k$ where $x_k < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $|x_{n_0}|<1$ for some $n_0$ we would get $$\sum_n x_n \frac1{n^2}\leq\sum_n |x_n| \frac1{n^2}=\sum_{n<n_0}|x_n|\frac1{n^2}+|x_{n_0}|\frac1{n_{0}^2}+\sum_{n>n_0}|x_n| \frac1{n^2}\\
<\sum_{n}\frac1{n^2}$$ contradicting
$\sum_n x_n\frac1{n^2}=\sum_n \frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: What if ${x_n}_0 < 0$?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: I think some how the fact that $x_n$ is infinitesimal must be taken into account somehow, I could have for instance $ ...+1/4 +...+1/16+... =...+ x_2*1/4 +...+ x_4*1/16 ...$if I let $x_2=1/4, x_4=4$ or  different combinations that keep the total sum the same if more than just one $x_n$ is not 1

Comment: This was a bad example because I forgot $x_n$ must be less than 1, but you get the point, since we can have a combination of  negative and positive $x_n$

Comment: This solution is right, but it should ends with a contradiction, since $(x_n) \in c_0$, and conclude that the statement is false.